# DotNetOpenAuth manual handling of authorized token

Tags: oauth, openid, dotnetopenauth

So I've got OpenID+OAuth hybrid working with DotNetOpenAuth when connecting to google. It gives me back a Authorized token so I need to exchange it for an access token.

I seem to be coming in about midway through a normal OAuth workflow in DotNetOpenAuth. I also seem to be missing somethings that DotNetOpenAuth wants like the the token secret and verifier. However according to the graph [here](http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#anchor9) I shouldn't need them.

Any ideas how to easily swap the auth token for an access token with DotNetOpenAuth?

Comment: I think DotnetOpenAuth is just a little to 'enterprisey' for me to grasp currently. The OpenId part was easy enough but the Oauth part makes my head hurt. Unfamiliarity with the Oauth spec and the library isn't helping anything. 

I used DevDefined Oauth and got the access token back without any issues. Feel lame using two diffrent Oauth libraries, but it works. Kludgy but I'll get around to figuring out DotNetOpenAuth later.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're talking about the OpenID+OAuth hybrid I expect you're writing a web app (as opposed to an installed app).  DotNetOpenAuth should only be asking you for a verifier code if you're using the `DesktopConsumer` class, which is inappropriate for you.  Use the `WebConsumer` class instead and the verifier will be taken care of for you.  Swapping the request token for an access token will be automatic as you call the simple methods on `WebConsumer`, I hope.

As for the token secret, all token secrets are managed by *your* implementation of `ITokenManager`, which will save and retrieve token secrets on demand within your database.